# Creating a fog effect that varies with alpha

Tags: colors, lua, blending, love2d

I'm trying to implement "fog-of-war" in a mapping tool I'm developing.

For each grid cell, if a cell is "fogged", the color is set to grey multiplied by the cell's current color. Otherwise, the cell color is set to whatever color the cell normally should be.

Below is my `draw` function.

```
for x = 0, (self.gridSize - 1) * self.scale, self.scale do
        for y = 0, (self.gridSize - 1) * self.scale, self.scale do
            local mouseX, mouseY = camera:mousepos()

            local curCell = self:getCell(x, y, true)
            local state = Grid:getState(x, y, true)

            if fog and curCell.fogged then
                local color = multiplyColors(curCell.color, {100,100,100,10})
                color[4] = 150
                if curCell:getState() == 1 then
                    love.graphics.setColor(color)
                else
                    love.graphics.setColor({100, 100, 100, 100})
                end
                love.graphics.rectangle('fill', x, y, self.scale, self.scale)
            elseif math.floor(mouseX / self.scale) == math.floor(x / self.scale) and math.floor(mouseY / self.scale) == math.floor(y / self.scale) then
                love.graphics.setColor(255, 0, 0, 30)
                love.graphics.rectangle('fill', x, y, self.scale, self.scale)

            elseif state == 1 then
                love.graphics.setColor(curCell.color)
                love.graphics.rectangle('fill', x, y, self.scale, self.scale)

            elseif state == 0 and self.bGridLines then
                love.graphics.setColor(100, 100, 100, 10)
                love.graphics.rectangle('line', x, y, self.scale, self.scale)
            end
        end
    end
```

And here's the `multiplyColors` function

```
function multiplyColors(c1, c2)
    local newColor = {}

    newColor[1] = math.floor((c1[1] * c2[1]) / 255)
    newColor[2] = math.floor((c1[2] * c2[2]) / 255)
    newColor[3] = math.floor((c1[3] * c2[3]) / 255)

    return newColor

end
```

While this creates [an okay-looking effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSUrh.png), I need the ability to set the fog opacity.

For example, if I change the line `color[4] = 150` to `color[4] = 255`, the desired output should be [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0xA2.png) instead of [what I actually get when changing that line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8BZz.png). Likewise, changing the line to `color[4] = 0` yields [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTviF.png) (which admittedly looks sorta neat) instead of [something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koT0V.png)

Here is a link to the complete repository: https://github.com/camdenb/DnD-Map-Creator

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to get different opacity levels in your fog would be to draw the fog over the whole screen by writing outside your loops:

```
love.graphics.setBackgoundColor(100, 100, 100) -- fog, everywhere
```

Afterward, if a cell is foggy then draw it with a lower alpha value to expose the fog underneath.

```
   if fogged and curCell.fogged then
      local c = curCell.color
      -- you can change 100 for various amounts of fog
      -- 0 means all fog and 255 means no fog
      love.graphics.setColor(c[1], c[2], c[3], 100)
      -- more code to draw...
   end
```

You may want to experiment with different blend modes. The [LÖVE wiki](https://www.love2d.org/wiki/BlendMode_Formulas) has a few examples to get different effects when blending the fog background with the cells being drawn over top.

Comment: It works, thanks! Interestingly, `local c = curCell.color` then `c[4] = 100` sets `curCell`'s alpha to 0 (instead of _only_ `c`'s value, which is the intended effect). I guess I have more to learn about the way Lua variables work!

Comment: [Here's a link](http://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html) to the Lua reference about the relationships between tables and variables assigned to tables.

_A table is always anonymous. There is no fixed relationship between a variable that holds a table and the table itself._

Comment: `local c = curCell.color` and then `love.graphics.setColor(c[1], c[2], c[3], 100)` is another option, if you don't want to create so many temporary tables.

Comment: Yep, that's what I did :)